# Establishing relationships in a database between multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, relational-database

I have a web application which allows users to join multiple groups.

I have a 'users' table which stores details about the users (id, email, password, etc.) and a 'groups' table which stores details about the available groups (id, name, owner of group).

I have been researching the best way to store group memberships (i.e. which users are in which group, bearing in mind they can be members of multiple) - however I am still not sure what the most efficient solution would be.

Would you recommend I:-

- Create a second table called 'group_memberships' and store the user's ID along with the corresponding group ID?
- Store an array alongside the group particulars in the 'groups' table with the user IDs of its members?
- Approach this task a different way?

The DBMS I am using is phpMyAdmin.

Comment: The first method is the accepted way to store such lists in a relational database.  It is called a "junction table".

Answer (score 2):

I would definitely go with option 1 - creating the junction table 'group_memberships' - I have used this approach many times without problems.  **Don't forget to add an Index** on the new table 'group_memberships' for columns: 'groupID' and 'userID'.

Option 2 is not scalable for a large amount of data, especially if groups have a lot of users.

**UPDATE:**

For info on Indexes, here is a good (and short) blog: https://blog.viaduct.io/mysql-indexes-primer/.

Comment: I understand I am digressing slightly from the question, but what's an index and how does it affect the relationship?

Comment: No problem - I've updated my answer to include a link to a blog that explains about Indexes.  (You should mark one of the answers as solved if you're problem has been answered)

Answer (score 2):

I would advise you to go with option 1; where you have a Mapping Table for linking Users & Groups.

The Users Table will have PK on User_ID.
The Groups table will have PK on Group_ID.
The Mapping table will have User_ID(FK) and Group_ID(FK).
Now you should have PK on these two columns together.
This will ensure you don't have duplicate entries.

Answer (score 2):

What you're describing is called a *many-to-many* relationship in database terms. A user can belong to multiple groups, and groups have more than one user (or else they wouldn't be "groups"!).

Your first idea, the `group_memberships` table, is the accepted best way to model this relationship. Although you'll want to name it `users_groups` or something similar to reflect the fact it *relates* or *associates* those two tables. At its most basic, this association table needs three columns:

1. ID (primary key)
2. user_id (foreign key)
3. group_id (foreign key)

By JOINing to this table ON either user_id or group_id, you can find the related records from either side of the relationship. And you can do it right from a SQL query, without any additional code like you'd need if you stored an array.

Answer (score 0):

The first option is a right choice. Actually it is a materialized view for both user table and group table.

Just think materialized view as a extra table or a redundant data structure that denormalizes the user properties and group properties together for quick search.

Since if we do not have the view, when we query a group id to list all its users, we have to filter millions of users to check if he/she is in the certain group. It is a performance nightmare!

Mysql has tools to build this view very efficiently. You may build secondary index on this view columns for quick search, say, group id, group name, user id, user name or something else you hope to search with.

good luck :-)